# Warning while trying to hyphenation word with special caracters

Tags: latex

I am trying to get rid of some warning messages related to hyphenation of Brazilian words. I am using

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

and I have words like ***conteúdo*** and ***serviços*** in my text. The pdf generated is all right, but the following warning is being generated:

```
Overfull \hbox (4.6673 too wide) in paragraph at lines..
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 Uma ta-refa de-sa-fi-a-dora no pla-ne-ja-mento de ca-
pa-ci-da de de pro-ve-do-res de conte^^Sudo
```

**conte^^Sudo** should be **con-te-ú-do**. I tried to make a macro like

`\newcommand{\conteudo}{con\-te\-ú\-do}`

And the warning was gone. But there is no blank space to separate this word from the next one, so if I have **conteúdo high**, sometimes a get **conteúdohigh** using these types of macros. I am using TexMaker and the letters after the first \ are with another color, I thought that maybe it could be generating some problems too.

I wanted to know if it's possible to define a hyphenation for some words even if they have special characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the space to be present, you need to put braces after you invoke your command.

```
\newcommand{\conteudo}{con\-te\-ú\-do}
...
\conteudo{} high  % produces conteúdo high every time.
```

Otherwise, you can control the hyphenation everywhere by specifying it with the `\hyphenation` command, as shown [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Text_Formatting#Hyphenation).

Comment: Your suggestion work. But I tried to define hyphenation like `\hyphenation{con\-te\-ú\-do}` and it didn't work. I found [here](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=24&t=20984) a similar problem, but it was solved using XeLaTeX, which I don't want to use. I noted that it's possible to write **con\-te\-ú\-do** in the text itself, to get rid of the warning message too.